# Rails model scaffolding not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

In a very simple rails project from a tutorial I run `rails generate scaffold Event title:string date:date description:text`. Everything is ok except that when I open the EventsController.rb I see that the show method is empty:

```
def show
end
```

In the video of the course I see that this method is not supposed to be empty and should contain things like `@event = Event.find(params[:id])`. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Did you look if it's somewhere in `before_filter`?

Comment: Are you using Rails 4? (you can check that in Gemfile)

Comment: Yes, it is in the before_filter and yes I'm using Rails 4. Marek, please post this as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 4 the style is changed to getting particular resource based on id. So it is moved to before_folter section.

You controller may be like,

```
before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def set_event
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end
```

Please see the controller private methods.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Indeed this is the case. One more small thing though: this covers `the @user = Event.find(params[:id])` part but there is still a `respond_to do |format|` which does not exist in the show method or in any private method. How does it respond depending on the format in this case?

Comment: it doesn't need that. it will automatically respond back according to your response.

Comment: Yes, you are exactly correct. Also did you see the file show.json.jbuilder ? under the views/users/ directory. This is also a new default feature added (gem jbilder) with rails 4. So when you access the /users.json this file is rendered.